# Is there a good solution to deal with session inactivity using session set save handler for database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using `session_set_save_handler` to save session data to the database. My code works fine. I would like to handle session inactivity in the my custom handler itself. I would like to logout the user after X number of minutes. In my `Read` method, my select query returns a timestamp (lastchanged column) for the session id with session data. I tried calling `session_destroy` if the difference between timestamp and current time is greater than X minutes but then Write method is called again by the handler after the Destroy method.

```
session_set_save_handler(
            array($this, 'Open'),
            array($this, 'Close'),
            array($this, 'Read'),
            array($this, 'Write'),
            array($this, 'Destroy'),
            array($this, 'Gc'));
```

I tried using exit() but it doesn't gracefully logout. Is there a cleaner way to handle session inactivty?

Couple of other questions:

1) Should I change settings for save_handler to "User" in php.ini?
2) Should I explicitly expire the session using timestamp?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If a session has expired (create a sessions table in database to be sure of session end datetimes) you should start a new one and leave the old one in rest (the cookie will expire anyway). By the gc method you can set up a cleaning mechanizm to clear out your database from old session datas.

Comment: the sessions table is already there. If the sessions has expired and I detect that in the Read method how can I stop it from executing the Write method.

Comment: I have changed save_handler to "User" in php.ini because I am moving to database backed sessions. Should I revert that?

Comment: You don't have to be worried about the method executing the only important thing is that when a session expires start another one. I prefer the way of registering the handler from code not from php.ini becouse i can easily switch off the saving of session datas to database.

Comment: If you wan't to stop reading and writing any expired session data than you should do a check in the read and write method: if (SessionManager::Instance()->Expired()) {return} or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way to accomplish what you are trying is to have the `Read` know to return some empty value if the session has expired, and then use `setcookie` to manually destroy the session ID (normally the cookie name is `PHPSESSID`).

Comment: I tried to destroy the session ID using setcookie in my Read method after I know that the session has expired but it seems logout on every call to my custom handler. Also, if I return an empty string such as "DEACTIVATE" from my Read Method for session data, the Write method does not recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

I would put an index on the sessions expire time in the database and have a cron job to periodically tidy the database up (i.e. delete the expired ones). You can then off load this task to a part of the day when the traffic is lighter, or put the task as a low priority.

After all, does it really matter that the database contains expired sessions as long as they do not take up too much space?

BTW - This could be achieved by a few lines of SQL

Comment: I am not too concerned about needing a cron job.  My "Gc" method should be able to take care of this based on session.gc_maxlifetime setting. I am using this to run a "delete" sql with in conjunction with current time. My concern is with deleting a user session if the user is inactive for a period of time. GC kicks in when another user logs in and renders the first user inactive based on the time differential.